# Python Path Override

Tags: python, python-module

I have a directory structure like this:

```
PYTHONPATHDIR
    App1
        someModule.py
        utils.py  
    utils
        hasClassIWantToImport.py
```

And I want someModule to import something from utils.hasClassIWantToImport.  When I call:

```
from utils.hasClassIWantToImport import ClassIWant
```

it cannot resolve "hasClassIWantToImport" because it thinks I'm talking about the utils.py in the current directory.

How do I get around this?  I know I can rename one of the "utils" but would rather not...

Comment: It's not a good practice to give the same names to different modules/classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way that you are going to be able to maintain access to both `PYTHONPATHDIR/utils` and `PYTHONPATHDIR/App1/utils.py` simultaneously without referring to one of them relative to something else.

If you modify your path so that `PYTHONPATHDIR` is at the head of the list, then you can import `utils.hasClassIWantToImport` but you will lose access to `utils.py`.

About the best you can do is make `App1` a package by placing a `__init__.py` file into it and munge your path like @Gryphius suggested (i.e. put `/path/to/utils` at the head of `sys.path`).  When you want access to `utils.hasClassIWantToImport`, you

```
from utils.hasClassIWantToImport import ClassIWant
```

To import files relative to `utils.py`, you will then

```
from App1.utils import ClassIWantFromApp1
```

However, this is a horrible hack just to avoid renaming `utils.py`.  I recommend saving yourself the long-term headache of path manipulation and just rename that file.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I have understood your directory setup correctly, but you could try:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/utils')
from hasClassIwantToImport import ClassIWant
```